# Discrepancy in data while pasting to excel

Tags: excel, ssms

Can anyone help with the following?

When pasting data from database to excel, there is a discrepancy in row number is observed. e.g. if 10000 rows are present in a table in database, while copying them all and pasting into an excel, 9926 rows are pasting. How can it be overcome?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should tell us which database you are using, and, even more important, which tool you are using to query your database.  What you are describing should not be happening if using any of the enterprise database tools, e.g. SSMS or Workbench.

Comment: I am using SSMS and this is happening in production server.

Comment: So you're telling us that you did select all, followed by copy with headers, then paste into Excel, and some of the rows are being dropped?

Comment: yes that is the case

Comment: I can't help, because I can't reproduce this behavior locally, and in fact, I've never seen it happen.  Try to give an example which can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

instead of pasting the data, I would suggest you import the data using the "data" tab -> get data using database or other source.